# Value attribute of a text box retains old value even after new value has been keyed in

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

This is the HTML I have for a text box on a form:

```
<input type="text" onblur="javascript:itemLostFocus('18A3461989AC0244E050A20AB17C4671');" onkeydown="javascript:itemChanging('18A3461989AC0244E050A20AB17C4671');" value="972" name="18A3461989AC0244E050A20AB17C4671" maxlength="3" size="3"/>
```

What I do next is update the text box input to 123 from 972. Now if I check the value attribute of the same text box using the `getAttribute("value")` method of Selenium WebDriver, it still shows 972 and not 123.

What attribute should I look for to retrieve the value 123?

Comment: How do you enter the value? Through Javascript? Show the code if possible pelase

Comment: is it possible that the textbox is read only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Selenium WebDriver executes so quickly, when you are updating the input value, your `getAttribute("value")` method is executing before your input gets a chance to update.

In your BasePage you need a `waitFor boolean`

```
protected void waitFor(BooleanCondition condition) {
    waitFor(condition, "(none)");
}
```

And in your Object page you need to call the `waitFor` method after you update your input and before you call `getAttribute("value")`

```
public ObjectPage readValue(String value) {
    // whatever update happens
    waitFor(Conditions.elementIsNotDisplayed("#waiting_dialog"));
    return this;
}
```